# Android App --- My textview text isn't showing in the app, but shows in the design view

Tags: android

In the following code, the 'user' and 'pass' text above the text boxes are not showing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/login" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="User:" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"></EditText>
        <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Pass:" android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"></TextView>
        <EditText android:inputType="textPassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"></EditText>
        <Button android:text="Enter" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2" android:layout_marginTop="19dp" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry it's a bit big and long but I have searched this question and tried to find solutions but can't apply them to this very well. What am I doing wrong? Could someone guide me through how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that, can you please post the full XML of your layout. This seems to be only a snippet w/o a surrounding layout. There may be something missing. And maybe reformat the XML a bit, it's very hard to read with that horizontal scrolling and long lines.

Comment: I've added in the surrounding XML -- From the searches I have done, I think it /could/ be related to the relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be that your background of the outer RelativeLayout is White (#ffffff), by default (correct me if I'm wrong) the text in Android is white, with a black background. Try messing around with [themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). For a quick fix trying setting the android:textColor="#000000" on your TextViews or something similar.

Comment: Just was testing the issue, and I can confirm that. The text shows when you set a black color on it. You may also just use a LinearLayout with android:orientation="vertical" if you stack views like you did here. That should be easier and requires less code.

Comment: Can I not use the relative layout as it gives a nicer and more dynamic interface.

Comment: You sure can, but in this case it does not make any difference. You can archieve this look with both layouts, but you don't have to write android:layout_below=".." all the time, since its the nature of a LinearLayout to align the Views below each other.

Comment: Sorry for my late response - No, it doesn't work even if I set the colour to black.